# Jquery - How to scroll on element id after click if condition is true or false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with my Jquery i want to scroll on element only if element if visible, if it is hidden don't scroll. Can you help me ? Thank you very much.

jQuery:

```
$('#menu').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#nav').slideToggle('300');
if($("#nav").css('visibility') == 'hidden') {

}else{
    $('#nav h4 a').trigger('click');
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#nav").offset().top
  }, 1000);   


}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" style="border:none;" >
  <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a id="menu" href="#"><img width="37px" src="/css/menu.png" alt="menu" /></a> <!-- icon to show element or hide -->
  </div>
</div>


<div id="nav" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b"> <!-- Code for element where to scroll -->
            <h4>Menu</h4>                                        
            <div data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            ..content
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle and share here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#menu').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#nav').slideToggle('300');
  if($('#nav').is(':visible') ) // if true means
  {
    $('#nav h4 a').trigger('click');
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#nav").offset().top
    }, 1000); 
  }
});
console.log($('#nav').is(':visible') )//it will return true or false
```